# Creating MS Word documents with Go OLE binding

Tags: go, ms-word, ole

I've been playing around and learning how to make Word docs programmatically. I know it can easily be done using `pywin32`. This simple snippet retrieves the default Visual Basic "code" inside the new Word doc.

```py
import win32com.client
 
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
document = word.Documents.Add()
document.VBProject.Name = "TEST"
wordModule = document.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument") # WORKS

input()
```

You can then add VB code to `wordModule`.

I wanted to do the same using Golang. There is a OLE binding for Go, the code is on Github -> https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole

It's a bit less user friendly but I managed to make it work, except that I'm not able to retrieve the default `VBComponents`.

The default code resides in "ThisDocument" and can be retrieved with the simple python code `document.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument")` except that, it doesn't work in Go...
You can see in the code below that I tried to get "ThisDocument" using multiple ways, without success. Each time, the error message is `panic: Unknown name.`

```golang
// +build windows

package main

import (
    "fmt"

    ole "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole/oleutil"
)

func main() {
    defer ole.CoUninitialize()

    ole.CoInitialize(0)
    unknown, _ := oleutil.CreateObject("Word.Application")
    word, _ := unknown.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
    oleutil.PutProperty(word, "Visible", true)

    documents := oleutil.MustGetProperty(word, "Documents").ToIDispatch()
    document := oleutil.MustCallMethod(documents, "Add").ToIDispatch()

    vbproject := oleutil.MustGetProperty(document, "VBProject").ToIDispatch()
    oleutil.PutProperty(vbproject, "Name", "TEST")

    // oleutil.MustCallMethod(vbproject, "VBComponents", "ThisDocument").ToIDispatch() --> panic: Unknown name.

    // oleutil.MustGetProperty(vbproject, "VBComponents", "ThisDocument").ToIDispatch() --> panic: Unknown name.

    // vbcomponents := oleutil.MustGetProperty(vbproject, "VBComponents").ToIDispatch()
    // oleutil.MustGetProperty(vbcomponents, "ThisDocument").ToIDispatch() --> panic: Unknown name.

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

    oleutil.PutProperty(document, "Saved", true)
    oleutil.CallMethod(documents, "Close", false)
    oleutil.CallMethod(word, "Quit")
    word.Release()
}
```

Any ideas on why it doesn't work?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `"github.com/go-ole/go-ole"` has a bug when using `ForEach`. `VBComponets` is a `Collection`, so you have to iterate as stated by Microsoft doc

> Use the VBComponents collection to access, add, or remove components in a project. A component can be a form, module, or class. The VBComponents collection is a standard collection that can be used in a For...Each block.

This line -> https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole/blob/master/oleutil/oleutil.go#L106
should be replace by

```golang
newEnum, err := disp.CallMethod("_NewEnum")
```

Now it works as intended.